# Does RenderComponentPresentation() retrieve minor version of the component?

Tags: 2013, publishing, componentpresentation, bundles

We are retrieve a component content by using below method by passing the component ID and Component Template ID. However, when I publish the component using bundle, my changes are not reflected. On debugging I find that the minor version/in-workflow version of the component is not pulled and only the major version is published again.

```
functs.RenderComponentPresentation(componentId, componentTemplateId);
```

Does this retrieve minor version? Or should I change anything in my code to retrieve the minor version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While publishing through Workflow Activities you need to consider the following in order to publish the "Editable" version

1. The Item must have the same Approval Status as the Publication Target selected for publishing
2. Ensure the Activity has the same Approval Status as the Publication Target and make sure you finish the Activity before you publish (Finishing the Activity will apply the Approval Status to the items)

You can also use the "Publish Workflow Version if Possible" feature while publishing outside Workflow. It will check if the Item Approval Status is lower or the same as the Publication Target Approval Status